# I am unsure why my output is always returning false

Tags: java

I am trying to do a Distributive Law in my code but somehow, the output always returns false.

Here is an example of my Set class with Union, Intersection and Equality method in it:

```java
class Set {

    // Instance variable.
    private ArrayList<Zodiac> s;

    // Default constructor.
    public Set() {
        this.s = new ArrayList<Zodiac>();
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    public Set(Set otherSet) {
        this.s = new ArrayList<Zodiac>(otherSet.s);
        for (Zodiac z : otherSet.s) {
            s.add(z);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my distributiveExample method:

```
private static void distributiveExample() {

    Set setA1 = new Set(getASet());
    Set setB1 = new Set(getASet());
    Set setC1 = new Set(getASet());

    Set setA2 = new Set(setA1);
    Set setB2 = new Set(setB1);
    Set setC2 = new Set(setC1);

    System.out.printf("We wish to prove: A U (B I C) = (A U B) I (A U C).\n");

    System.out.printf("\n");

    System.out.printf("Given sets\n");
    System.out.printf("\t A = {%s}%n", setA1);
    System.out.printf("\t B = {%s}%n", setB1);
    System.out.printf("\t C = {%s}%n", setC1);

    System.out.printf("\n");

    System.out.printf("\t A = {%s}%n", setA2);
    System.out.printf("\t B = {%s}%n", setB2);
    System.out.printf("\t C = {%s}%n", setC2);

    System.out.printf("\n");

    setB1.intersection(setC1);
    setA1.union(setB1);

    System.out.printf("LHS analysis\n");
    System.out.printf("\t LHS = {%s}%n", setA1);

    setA2.union(setB2);
    setA2.union(setC2);
    setA2.intersection(setA2);

    System.out.printf("RHS analysis\n");
    System.out.printf("\t RHS = {%s}%n", setA2);

    System.out.printf("\n");

    System.out.printf("Conclusion\n");
    System.out.printf("\t LHS = RHS is %b%n", setA1.equality(setA2));
    System.out.printf("-----------------------------------------\n");

    System.out.printf("\n");

    }
```

if LHS = RHS:

[image]

in the output, the LHS = RHS is true but somehow its return false. Therefore, I am unsure what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: What are these `Set`s? What type are their elements? If they are instances of `java.util.Set`, don't use raw types, but instead `Set<String>` (or whatever).

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think he programmed his own class and called it Set, so he might not be using a raw type but just a non-generic class.

Comment: @Ben you should add the complete code (or at least the implementation of your Set class) in order to have a look.

Comment: You are updating the original sets. You should create an empty set before doing an intersection or union operation, so original sets are preserved for later use.

Comment: @Rocco, I have added a snippet of my set class.

Comment: @Ben since you are using a Zodiac class in your set, you should also post this one, specifically check if equals() / hashCode methods are properly defined. I suspect that the problem is there, but without the complete code I can't tell anything

Comment: @Rocco, i have added the Zodiac class.

Comment: Your copy constructor is copying each element of the other set twice. All you need to do is `s = new ArrayList<>(otherSet.s);` which will create a copy of the other set. You shouldn't then loop through and copy each element as you've already got a copy of it and you'd be copying it twice. Having said that, I don't know why your printf statement shows that they are equal after copying. Perhaps the code you're running is not the same as what you've posted, or your `toString()` method is not showing the full ArrayList.

Comment: @k314159 what do you meant by printf statement shows that they are equal?

Comment: @Ben the code is still incomplete, please post a complete runnable example, this does not mean post all your code, but something that can be compiled and executed that reproduce the problem, otherwise we can only go on with hypothesis.

Comment: @Ben when I said "printf statement shows that they are equal" I meant it just implies they are equal due to their printed appearance being the same. It doesn't mean they're actually equal.

Comment: @Rocco i have updated the output.

Comment: We need to see at least the `addElement` and the `toString` methods of your Set class in order to see why it's going wrong.

Comment: I added some missing methods that you hadn't shown here, and ran the code, and it outputs "true" as expected. You can run it and see the result at https://ideone.com/COvdOT

Comment: @k314159, yep i have fixed my issue, thank you so much!

Comment: What was missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you might be missing is that when you use the `=` operator in: `Set setA2 = setA;` you are not creating another object setA2 that is identical to setA.

What the `=` operator does in your code is that it allows you to have setA2 point to the same reference that setA points to.

So, since I suspect that the `Set` datatype is something custom made by you, you can create a method that copies **the contents** of another `Set` and feeds them as contents to the `Set` you want to create.

In addition to the above, one good thing for the debugging of your code would be to print the two objects you compare just before the comparison happening.
Like this:

```
    System.out.printf("RHS analysis\n");
    System.out.printf("\t RHS = {%s}%n", setA2);

    /* at this point you might have missed the LHS analysis output 
    after the modifications */ 

    System.out.printf("LHS analysis\n");
    System.out.printf("\t LHS = {%s}%n", setA);


    System.out.printf("\n");

    System.out.printf("Conclusion\n");
    System.out.printf("\t LHS = RHS is %b%n", setA.equality(setA2));
    System.out.printf("-----------------------------------------\n");

    System.out.printf("\n");
```

If both of the above did not work, then most likely the fault is inside the Set.union() & Set.intersection() you have created.

In that case you can use `Java.Util.Collections` class interface extension called "Set" for both of those methods:

- union: `setA2.addAll(setB2);`
- intersection: `setA2.retainAll(setA2);`

Comment: I have added a snippet of my Set class along with the Union and Intersection method.